# How to find the first instance of a "lower case character" in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

How to find the first instance of a "lower case character" in a cell using VBA in Excel?
I have tried using ASCII values but that didn't work.

Comment: Not enough information. "any" lower case character? Or a specific one? What is your code so far. What was not successful?

Comment: Hi teyln.. I have extracted some text from an XML file...The extracted text has some text in upper and some in lower case..For eg. ABCdefGHIjkl..Now I want to concatenate ABC->GHI and delete the rest..

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function DeleteLowerCasesLike(InputString As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(InputString)
        If Mid(InputString, i, 1) Like "[a-z]" Then
            InputString = Left(InputString, i - 1) & Mid(InputString, i + 1)
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next

    DeleteLowerCasesLike = InputString
End Function
```

Another `RegExp` solution which needs to addig referance to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0` (In the `VBA` window, `Tools->Referances` menu)

```
Private Function DeleteLowerCasesRegExp(InputString As String)
    Dim RE As New RegExp
    With RE
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[a-z]"
        DeleteLowerCasesRegExp = .Replace(InputString, "")
    End With
End Function
```

And another solution nor `Like` neither `RegExp` is used:

```
Private Function DeleteLowerCasesAsc(InputString As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(InputString)
        If Mid(InputString, i, 1) = Empty Then Exit For
        If Asc(Mid(InputString, i, 1)) >= 97 And Asc(Mid(InputString, i, 1)) <= 122 Then
            InputString = Left(InputString, i - 1) & Mid(InputString, i + 1)
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next

    DeleteLowerCasesAsc = InputString
End Function
```

Another solution in which `replace` function is used:

```
Private Function DeleteLowerCasesReplace(InputString As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 97 To 122
            InputString = Replace(InputString, Chr(i), "")
    Next

    DeleteLowerCasesReplace = InputString
End Function
```

Comment: Hi ... I have extracted some text from an XML file...The extracted text has some text in upper and some in lower case..For eg. ABCdefGHIjkl..Now I want to concatenate ABC->GHI and delete the rest..

Comment: @Sahil Oberoi Answer has been replaced with two different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following small *UDF:*

```
Public Function Findlower(rin As Range) As Long
    Dim v As String, CH As String, i As Long

    Findlower = 0
    v = rin.Text
    L = Len(v)
    For i = 1 To L
        If Mid(v, i, 1) Like "[a-z]" Then
            Findlower = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

It will return the position of the first instance of any lower case letter in a string:

[image]

Comment: Hi ... I have extracted some text from an XML file...The extracted text has some text in upper and some in lower case..For eg. ABCdefGHIjkl..Now I want to concatenate ABC->GHI and delete the rest..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RegExp` in a UDF to avoid looping through each character:

```
Function FirstLower(strIn As String) as String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "[a-z]"
    .ignorecase = False
If .test(strIn) Then
    Set objRegM = .Execute(strIn)(0)
    FirstLower = objRegM.firstindex + 1
Else
    FirstLower = "no match"
End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hi ... I have extracted some text from an XML file...The extracted text has some text in upper and some in lower case..For eg. ABCdefGHIjkl..Now I want to concatenate ABC->GHI and delete the rest..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the first part in your string that is in lower case:

```
Public Function DeletFirstLowerPart(strTemp As String) As String
    Dim strResult As String, i As Long, findLower As Boolean

    strResult = ""
    findLower = False
    For i = 1 To Len(strTemp)
        If (Mid(strTemp, i, 1) Like "[a-z]") Then
            findLower = True
        Else
            If findLower = True Then
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strTemp, i)
                DeletFirstLowerPart = strResult
                Exit Function
            End If
            strResult = strResult & Mid(strTemp, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    DeletFirstLowerPart = strResult
End Function
```

```
DeletFirstLowerPart("ABCdefGHI") = "ABCGHI"
DeletFirstLowerPart("ABCdefGHIjkl") = "ABCGHIjkl"
```